# Getting all data in table base on some highlighted row

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, xpath

This is the scenario. I have a `<table>` like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Coca cola</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Pepsi</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Water</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, user will highlight 2 first rows, for example. My task is to extract the appropriate 3 `XPaths` to get data in each column.

Does anyone have any idea about this? I have thought about it a lot but haven't found any good solution yet. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

**EDIT!!!**

You can try using `Scraper` from `Google Chrome` extension for more detail. What I want is just a little bit like it. Thanks.

Comment: What _have_ you tried? Anyway, you will have to loop over all rows and fetch the respective columns.

Comment: @Forte_201092: Check my answer out, that's what you have to do using xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you add a class to the highlighted rows, and after highlighting your html DOM is like this:

```
<table id="highlights">
    <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlighted">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Coca cola</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="highlighted">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Pepsi</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Water</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I added `id="highlights"` just to make it distingushable, if you have other tables in the page. then this is what you have to do:

```
var noXpath = "//table[@id='highlights']/tbody/tr[@class='highlighted']/td[1]/text()";
var nameXpath = "//table[@id='highlights']/tbody/tr[@class='highlighted']/td[2]/text()";
var priceXpath = "//table[@id='highlights']/tbody/tr[@class='highlighted']/td[3]/text()";

function getData(xpathQuery) {
    var iterator = document.evaluate(xpathQuery, document.body, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var nodes = [];
    var node;
    while (node = iterator.iterateNext()) {
        nodes.push(node.nodeValue);
    }
    return nodes;
}
var noData=getData(noXpath);
var namesData=getData(nameXpath);
var priceData=getData(priceXpath);
```

and this is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HjwqH/).